# Couldn't find file 'bootstrap-transition'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

Error message, when I open project: **couldn't find file 'bootstrap-transition'
(in /home/ubuntu/workspace/app/assets/javascripts/w.js.coffee:3)**

In file w.js.coffee line 3 is #= require bootstrap-transition.

Which gem do I need to download or what needs to be customized in a rails project?

Gem file:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '~>3.2.12'
gem 'mysql2', '0.3.13'
gem 'haml-rails'
gem 'haml-contrib'
gem 'jquery-rails', '~>2.0.2'
gem 'paperclip', '~>3.4.0'

# gem 'authlogic'
gem 'devise', '~>2.2.3'
gem 'devise-encryptable'
gem 'devise-async'
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'omniauth-vkontakte'

gem 'dynamic_form'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'russian'
gem 'recaptcha', :require => 'recaptcha/rails'
gem 'will_paginate'
gem 'state_machine'
gem 'settingslogic'
gem 'meta_search'
# gem 'meta_where', '1.0.1' # -> Using Rails 3.1? You want to take a look at Squeel instead
gem 'squeel'
gem 'ancestry'
gem 'retina_tag'
gem 'strong_parameters'
gem 'role-rails'
gem 'dropzonejs-rails'

gem 'daemons'
gem 'delayed_paperclip'

# gem 'rufus-scheduler', '2.0.10'
gem 'whenever', :require => false
gem 'thinking-sphinx', '~>2.0.14'
# gem 'ts-delayed-delta', :require => 'thinking_sphinx/deltas/delayed_delta'
gem 'resque', :require => 'resque/server'
gem 'resque-scheduler', '2.0.1'
gem 'resque-retry'
gem 'redis-namespace', '1.3.0'
gem 'ts-resque-delta', '~>1.2.4'
gem 'RedCloth'
gem 'rails_autolink'

gem 'acts-as-taggable-on'
gem 'acts_as_list'
gem 'tzinfo'
# gem 'aws-s3', :require => 'aws/s3'
gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 1.5.7'
gem 'aws-ses', :require => 'aws/ses'
gem 'newrelic_rpm'
gem "airbrake"
gem 'draper'
gem 'redis-rails'
# gem 'robokassa', git: 'git://github.com/glebtv/robokassa.git'
gem 'rest-client'
gem 'asset_sync'
gem 'private_pub'
gem 'thin'

# gem 'emoji4rails'
gem 'rails_emoji'
gem 'rumoji', git: 'git://github.com/mwunsch/rumoji'
gem 'escape_utils'
gem 'cocoon'

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails'
  gem 'coffee-rails'
  gem 'compass-rails'
  gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.1.1.0'
  gem 'therubyracer'
  gem 'execjs'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
  gem 'oily_png'
  # gem 'font-awesome-rails'
  gem 'turbo-sprockets-rails3'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails',        '2.5.0'
  gem 'factory_girl'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'rails3-generators',  '0.17.4'
  gem 'timecop',            '0.3.5'
  gem 'quiet_assets'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'capybara-user_agent'
  gem 'pry-byebug'
end

group :development do
  gem 'capistrano', '~>2.15.4', require: false
  gem 'capistrano-ext', require: false
  gem 'rvm-capistrano', require: false
  gem 'wirble'
  # gem 'hirb'
  gem 'git'
  gem 'letter_opener'
  gem 'rack-mini-profiler'
  gem 'mailcatcher'
end

group :production do
  gem 'unicorn'
end

gem 'tinymce-rails'
gem 'tinymce-rails-langs'
gem 'backup'
```

Comment: possibly this? https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails/issues/91

Comment: no, its not my issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After installing gem bootstrap-sass restart server.